# Drush 8 issue under Linux: 'drush up' ends with 'pm-updatestatus failed' while 'drush ups' works correctly

Tags: drush, updating

I'm hosted on a Linux server with Apache 2.2, PHP 5.5, MySQL 5.6 installed. I still run D6 sites for the moment, whose some modules I can update by using Drush 8 combined with the myDropWizard module.

The `drush up` command works correctly with all the sites except for this one:

```
[~/public_html/fr/sites/fr.mysite.com]# drush up
pm-updatestatus failed.                                              [error]
```

The curious thing is that the `drush ups` command does work and end correctly.

On the one hand, this issue prevents an easy update of the site's modules (even if it can be done module after module by using the `drush dl` command), on the other hand I'm afraid that it could cause problems when I'll migrate from D6 to D8 by using Drush 8.

Edit:

```
[~/public_html/fr/sites/fr.mysite.com]# drush -dv up
Using the Drush script found at /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.launcher using proc_open
Drush preflight prepare loaded autoloader at                         [preflight]
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/autoload.php [0.01 sec, 2.43 MB]
Starting Drush preflight. [0.01 sec, 2.43 MB]                                                                              [preflight]
Loading drushrc "/home/myuser/.drush/drushrc.php" into "home.drush" scope. [0.01 sec, 2.44 MB]                           [bootstrap]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.3-commandfiles-0-e781ef82ff5e93e79e640f0c0ab268c0 [0.02 sec, 2.5 MB]                                        [debug]
Scanning into /etc/drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.06 sec, 4.78 MB]                                                [debug]
Scanning into /etc/drush for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.06 sec, 4.78 MB]                                              [debug]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/.. for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.06 sec, 4.78       [debug]
MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/.. for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.07 sec, 4.78     [debug]
MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.07 sec, 4.79 MB]                                     [debug]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.drush for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.07 sec, 4.79 MB]                                   [debug]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/fr/../drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.07 sec, 4.79 MB]                    [debug]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/fr/../drush for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.07 sec, 4.79 MB]                  [debug]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/fr/drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.07 sec, 4.79 MB]                       [debug]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/fr/drush for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.07 sec, 4.79 MB]                     [debug]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/fr/sites/all/drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.07 sec, 4.8 MB]              [debug]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/fr/sites/all/drush for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.07 sec, 4.8 MB]            [debug]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/fr/sites/default for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.07 sec, 4.8 MB]                [debug]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/fr/sites/default for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.07 sec, 4.8 MB]              [debug]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.23 sec, 7.44 MB]                                                                                  [bootstrap]
Bootstrap to phase 6. [0.23 sec, 7.45 MB]                                                                                  [bootstrap]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.24 sec, 7.82 MB]                                                        [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal 6.38 root directory at /home/myuser/public_html/fr [0.25 sec, 7.99 MB]                                [bootstrap]
Find command files for phase 1 (max=6) [0.26 sec, 5.37 MB]                                                                     [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.3-commandfiles-1-1cc9f5fc7ac03ef4db1de660fcacf131 [0.26 sec, 5.37 MB]                                       [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.3-annotationfiles-1-818eef3e23f247f112c32dedc548471d [0.26 sec, 5.37 MB]                                    [debug]
Scanning into /etc/drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.26 sec, 5.38 MB]                                                [debug]
Scanning into /etc/drush for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.26 sec, 5.38 MB]                                              [debug]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/.. for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.26 sec, 5.38       [debug]
MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/.. for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.26 sec, 5.38     [debug]
MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.27 sec, 5.38 MB]                                     [debug]
Scanning into /home/myuser/.drush for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.27 sec, 5.39 MB]                                   [debug]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/fr/../drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.27 sec, 5.39 MB]                    [debug]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/fr/../drush for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.27 sec, 5.39 MB]                  [debug]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/fr/drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.27 sec, 5.39 MB]                       [debug]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/fr/drush for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.27 sec, 5.39 MB]                     [debug]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/fr/sites/all/drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.27 sec, 5.39 MB]             [debug]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/fr/sites/all/drush for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.27 sec, 5.39 MB]           [debug]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/fr/sites/fr.mysite.com for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.27 sec,        [debug]
5.39 MB]
Scanning into /home/myuser/public_html/fr/sites/fr.mysite.com for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.27 sec,      [debug]
5.39 MB]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.27 sec, 5.4 MB]                                                         [bootstrap]
Initialized Drupal site fr.mysite.com at sites/fr.mysite.com [0.27 sec, 5.4 MB]                        [bootstrap]
Find command files for phase 2 (max=6) [0.28 sec, 5.4 MB]                                                                      [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.28 sec, 5.4 MB]                                                [bootstrap]
Find command files for phase 3 (max=6) [0.28 sec, 5.41 MB]                                                                     [debug]
sql-query: SELECT 1; [0.29 sec, 5.55 MB]                                                                                      [notice]
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_4tvjIm --database=myuser_dru600fr --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drush_gicAk0
  1
sql-query: SHOW TABLES; [0.3 sec, 5.56 MB]                                                                                    [notice]
Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_eHsHw5 --database=myuser_dru600fr --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drush_aFJu7I
  access
  accesslog
  actions
  actions_aid
  advanced_help_index
  aggregator_category
  aggregator_category_feed
  aggregator_category_item
  aggregator_feed
  aggregator_item
  antispam_counter
  antispam_moderator
  antispam_spam_marks
  authmap
  batch
  better_formats_defaults
  blocks
  blocks_roles
  book
  boost_cache
  boost_cache_relationships
  boost_cache_settings
  boost_crawler
  boxes
  cache
  cache_block
  cache_content
  cache_emfield_xml
  cache_filter
  cache_form
  cache_media_youtube_status
  cache_menu
  cache_mollom
  cache_mydropwizard
  cache_page
  cache_panels
  cache_update
  cache_views
  cache_views_data
  captcha_points
  captcha_sessions
  checkout
  client
  client_system
  comments
  contact
  contemplate
  contemplate_files
  content_field_rencontre_type
  content_group
  content_group_fields
  content_node_field
  content_node_field_instance
  content_type_book
  content_type_content_publications
  content_type_image
  content_type_issue
  content_type_meeting
  content_type_page
  content_type_simplenews
  content_type_story
  content_type_video
  ctools_css_cache
  ctools_object_cache
  date_format_locale
  date_format_types
  date_formats
  discussthis
  discussthis_forums
  drupal_install_test
  excerpt
  filefield_paths
  files
  filter_formats
  filters
  flood
  forum
  history
  htmlarea
  image
  image_attach
  imagecache_action
  imagecache_preset
  imce_files
  img_assist_map
  inline
  languages
  locales_source
  locales_target
  masquerade
  masquerade_users
  media_youtube_metadata
  media_youtube_node_data
  menu_custom
  menu_links
  menu_router
  moderation_filters
  moderation_roles
  moderation_votes
  mollom
  mollom_form
  node
  node_access
  node_comment_statistics
  node_counter
  node_revisions
  node_type
  nodequeue_nodes
  nodequeue_queue
  nodequeue_roles
  nodequeue_subqueue
  nodequeue_types
  nodewords
  old_revisions
  page_manager_handlers
  page_manager_pages
  page_manager_weights
  panels_display
  panels_layout
  panels_mini
  panels_pane
  panels_renderer_pipeline
  path_redirect
  permission
  poll
  poll_choices
  poll_votes
  print_mail_node_conf
  print_mail_page_counter
  print_node_conf
  print_page_counter
  profile_fields
  profile_values
  queue
  relatedlinks
  relatedlinks_tracker
  role
  search_dataset
  search_index
  search_keywords_log
  search_node_links
  search_total
  semaphore
  sequences
  sessions
  simplenews_mail_spool
  simplenews_newsletters
  simplenews_scheduler
  simplenews_scheduler_editions
  simplenews_snid_tid
  simplenews_subscriptions
  stylizer
  system
  taxonomy_context_term
  taxonomy_context_vocabulary
  taxonomy_manager_merge
  term_data
  term_hierarchy
  term_node
  term_relation
  term_synonym
  titles_settings
  upload
  url_alias
  users
  users_roles
  variable
  view_argument
  view_exposed_filter
  view_filter
  view_sort
  view_tablefield
  view_view
  views_display
  views_object_cache
  views_view
  vocabulary
  vocabulary_node_types
  watchdog
  webform_role_node
  weblink
  weblinks
  weblinks_node
  wysiwyg
  wysiwyg_user
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_database() [0.33 sec, 5.59 MB]                                                    [bootstrap]
Successfully connected to the Drupal database. [0.33 sec, 5.79 MB]                                                         [bootstrap]
Find command files for phase 4 (max=6) [0.33 sec, 5.79 MB]                                                                     [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_full() [0.33 sec, 5.79 MB]                                                        [bootstrap]
session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at                                   [warning]
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:40) bootstrap.inc:1182 [0.33 sec, 5.83 MB]
session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at                               [warning]
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:40) bootstrap.inc:1182 [0.33 sec, 5.83 MB]
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at                                              [warning]
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:40) bootstrap.inc:736 [0.34 sec, 6.62 MB]
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at                                              [warning]
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:40) bootstrap.inc:737 [0.34 sec, 6.62 MB]
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at                                              [warning]
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:40) bootstrap.inc:738 [0.34 sec, 6.62 MB]
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at                                              [warning]
/home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/output.inc:40) bootstrap.inc:739 [0.34 sec, 6.62 MB]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.3-install_profile-c66f37279ee5a91ead31fe763f40c039 [0.57 sec, 21.01 MB]                                     [debug]
Find command files for phase 5 (max=6) [0.57 sec, 21.01 MB]                                                                    [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.3-install_profile-c66f37279ee5a91ead31fe763f40c039 [0.57 sec, 21.01 MB]                                     [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.3-commandfiles-5-01051f83954cf3e8358fafb43e707c82 [0.57 sec, 21.12 MB]                                      [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.3-annotationfiles-5-bf9e2f890cdde593d4615e9c13cd401a [0.58 sec, 21.39 MB]                                   [debug]
Drush bootstrap phase : bootstrap_drupal_login() [0.58 sec, 21.37 MB]                                                      [bootstrap]
Find command files for phase 6 (max=6) [0.58 sec, 21.4 MB]                                                                     [debug]
Found command: pm-update (commandfile=pm) [0.58 sec, 21.4 MB]                                                              [bootstrap]
Calling hook drush_pm_update [0.8 sec, 24.86 MB]                                                                               [debug]
Loading release_info engine. [0.8 sec, 24.91 MB]                                                                              [notice]
Loading version_control engine. [0.8 sec, 24.92 MB]                                                                           [notice]
Loading package_handler engine. [0.81 sec, 24.93 MB]                                                                          [notice]
Executing: wget --version
Loading update_status engine. [0.82 sec, 24.92 MB]                                                                            [notice]
Including /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/includes/../commands//pm/updatecode.pm.inc [0.82 sec, 24.93 MB]      [bootstrap]
Calling hook drush_pm_updatecode_validate [0.82 sec, 25.02 MB]                                                                 [debug]
Returned from hook drush_pm_updatecode_validate [0.82 sec, 25.02 MB]                                                           [debug]
Calling hook drush_pm_updatecode [0.82 sec, 25.03 MB]                                                                          [debug]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1.3-alias-path--1303f2fb8c44e5041e5bb02a40a7da2c [0.82 sec, 25.04 MB]                                         [debug]
Cache SET cid: 8.1.3-alias-path--1303f2fb8c44e5041e5bb02a40a7da2c [0.83 sec, 25.04 MB]                                         [debug]
Backend invoke: /usr/bin/php-cli /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php-cli  --backend=2   [command]
--verbose --debug --root=/home/myuser/public_html/fr --uri=http://fr.mysite.com
--db-url='mysql://myuser_fr:fr123@localhost/myuser_drupal600fr'  pm-updatestatus 2>&1 [0.83 sec, 25.05 MB]
/usr/bin/php-cli /home/myuser/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php-cli  --backend=2 --verbose          [notice]
--debug --root=/home/myuser/public_html/fr --uri=http://fr.mysite.com
--db-url='mysql://myuser_fr:fr123@localhost/myuser_drupal600fr'  pm-updatestatus 2>&1 [0.83 sec, 25.06 MB]
pm-updatestatus failed. [1.38 sec, 25.13 MB]                                                                               [error]
Returned from hook drush_pm_updatecode [1.38 sec, 25.07 MB]                                                                    [debug]
Changes made in drush_pm_updatecode have been rolled back. [1.38 sec, 25.07 MB]                                                [debug]
Command dispatch complete [1.38 sec, 25.03 MB]                                                                                [notice]
Returned from hook drush_pm_update [1.38 sec, 24.99 MB]                                                                        [debug]
Command dispatch complete [1.38 sec, 24.95 MB]                                                                                [notice]
 Timer  Cum (sec)  Count  Avg (msec) 
 page   1.101      1      1100.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found where the problem was: in the alias file, the 'db-url' was wrong. I've corrected it and now `drush up` seems to work well.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the correct answer

Comment: OK, it's been done.

Answer (score 0):

To know more detail about why a drush command fails you should add the -d and or -v flags to the command.  -d adds debug messages and -v increases the verbosity level of messages returned, from the docs:

> -d, --debug      Display even more information, including internal messages.
>   -v, --verbose    Display extra information about the command.

Comment: The question has been edited and the results of the `drush -dv up` command have been added.